# The _ character but not in math mode

Tags: math-mode, symbols

My TeX voodoo has some special behaviour for WIP documents. One of those is printing labels and filenames in marginpars whenever encountered. This breaks whenever there are labels and filenames that contain a `_` character.

While `\includegraphics{file_name}` and `\label{foo_bar}` are obviously ok, a simple

```
\begin{document}
[... has to appear after \begin{document} ...]
\let\somelabel\label
\def\label#1{%
    \somelabel{#1}%
    #1
}
```

breaks at `\label{foo_bar}` with the good old `!Missing $ inserted` at the first occurrence of a `\label` containing a `_` character. I tried some things to have latex replace the `_` but it seems the problem is recursive. :-)

The obvious solution would be to not use labels and filenames containing `_`-characters, but that's not feasible for my current projects. Can I make latex not trip over the `_`-character?

Comment: What exactly are you after? Maybe you wanna look at [the `showkeys` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/showcase) ?

Comment: @tohecz: That's exactly what I want! thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\def\stripone#1#2\endstripone{#2}
\def\abc#1{\begingroup\escapechar-1 \expandafter\string\csname#1\endcsname\endgroup}

\abc{123} % output: 123

\abc{1_2_3} % output: 1_2_3

\end{document}
```

The idea:

- `\csname blabla\endcsname` makes a control sequence `\blabla`
- `\string\blabla` prints verbatim `\blabla`
- `\escapechar-1` makes the `\` disappear
- `\expandafter` is there to make the expansion in the correct order
- `\begingroup ... \endgroup` so that the change of `\escapechar` is local
- We need proper fonts that contain `_` at the correct place in the font table. I prefer `lmodern` in `T1`-encouding.

---

However, for showing the labels, you might prefer [the `showkeys` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/showcase).

Comment: I will try this when I have some more time to spare. Right now showkeys solved all my problems. Thanks again!

Comment: Could you explain why your code works? I mean, what does (La)TeX do/think, when it sees the `_` character?

Comment: `\string` converts a control sequence to `\escapechar` (in our case this is nothing) followed by the name of the control sequence, where all characters get category code `12=other`, which means that `_` is no longer treated as subscript. See http://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html#string-rp